# Who is the father of Malina and Nathan?

Tags: heroes-reborn

I just binged the first season of "Heroes Reborn". Question contains spoilers!

It has been quite a while since I watched the original series "Heroes". At the very end of "Heroes Reborn" there is a sequel-baiting bit, in which the father of Malina and Nathan leaves some Tarot-cards for them in the ice-cream-parlor respectively the school locker. Angela Petrelli tells Malina the card was put there by their father and that he would be coming for them and no one could stop him.

Could somebody please tell me, if Claire Bennet got pregnant during the plot of Heroes and if so, by whom?

Comment: "*If that remains a mystery, please feel free to speculate!*" - no, speculation would be better placed in chat. Stack Exchange main sites are meant to be for questions with demonstrable answers, either based on canon evidence or backed up by solid reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have never seen the father of Claire's children on-screen, though he is featured in the companion book [*Save the Cheerleader, Destroy the World*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015H1ZW0E).

All we know about him is that Claire calls him Hammer, though that's not actually his name, and she met him in 2012 when he was rescued from an anti-evo lynch mob. He is described as moody and aggressive towards non-evos. At one point, he disappears unexpectedly.

He returns on September 27, 2013, where he and Claire conceive the twins, and then immediately disappears again.

Comment: Thank you! This raises more Questions than it answers, but I guess that was intended by the makers. I am curious wheter this "Hammer" will be the the one to be looking for the twins or if that character is changed, because he seems like some one-dimensional jog and I do not know if thats makes a good villian.

Comment: I'm sure the intent was to leave us with questions, but there's no telling how long before we find the answers. AFAIK there's no plans to release any more Heroes media at the moment.